# Installing RMagick on Windows

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I've done research on this and I've been at it on my one computer for hours and hours.

I've installed RMagick on my Desktop computer about 3 weeks ago, and it was fairly complicated.

I don't remember the exact steps I took, and I'm really frustrated.

I've installed ImageMagick onto my machine in the directory C:\ImageMagick

I've installed the Development kit too for Ruby.

I've also put the rmagick-rmagick-v2-2-g564f157 into the proper gems folder in my C:
It's in C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems

I'm getting the following errors:

I will type: `gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="c:\ImageMagick"'`

and get the following errors:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir="c:\ImageMagick"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160326-6132-157vnes.rb extconf.rb
'--with-opt-dir="c:\ImageMagick"
checking for main() in -lCORE_RL_magick_... no
searching PATH for the ImageMagick library...
checking for main() in -lCORE_RL_magick_... no
checking for main() in -lCORE_RL_magick_... no
checking for main() in -lCORE_RL_magick_... no
Can't install RMagick 2.15.4.
Can't find the ImageMagick library.
Retry with '--with-opt-dir' option.
Usage: gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="[path to ImageMagick]"'
e.g.
  gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="C:Program FilesImageMagick-6.9.1-
Q16"'
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-CORE_RL_magick_lib
        --without-CORE_RL_magick_lib
        --with-CORE_RL_magick_lib
        --without-CORE_RL_magick_lib
        --with-CORE_RL_magick_lib
        --without-CORE_RL_magick_lib
        --with-CORE_RL_magick_lib
        --without-CORE_RL_magick_lib
extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
/gems/rmagick-2.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
```

I'm so frustrated at this point. It worked on my Desktop computer, but won't work here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Late at the party. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513938/1903781) on how to install `rmagik` on windows 10.

Answer (score 8):

This is the one link which can help you with all the issues you will ever face while installing rmagick gem.

Found it after a lot of browsing and after it you might not need any other link to visit.

link:- https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/install-rmagick-gem-on-windows-7-8-10-imagemagick-6-9-4-q16-hdri-5492c3fef202

I hope it will save your time and efforts

Comment: This should be the right answer IMO as it contains all information and steps necessary to get this working on Windows.

Comment: I am getting errors on installation after following the above link tried 6.9.6 also 6.9.10 same errors

https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/6gMkPuNQ

 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: I am getting errors on installation after following the above link tried 6.9.6 also 6.9.10 same errors please refer to this 

6.9.6 : https://pastebin.com/embed_js/Ukjbyhq9
6.9.10 : pastebin.com/embed_iframe/6gMkPuNQ 

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Comment: This answer totally deserves to be the right one. Fully solved my issue here. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

What I do to install is the following:

1. Install ImageMagick with installer including (!) "development headers and libraries" See: http://www.graphity-consulting.com/files/2016/03/screenshot-installation-imagemagick-6.9.3-32bit-3.png
2. Open windows command prompt
3. Enhance path to include ImageMagick. E.g. `set PATH=d:\opt\ImageMagick;%PATH%`
4. Install gem using: `gem install rmagick -- --with-opt-dir=d:\opt\ImageMagick`

Note: I let `gem` download rmagick by itself and I pass path to ImageMagick in `--with-opt-dir` and also have it in my path.

**UPDATE:**

As @winter-young mentioned in comments: Do not mix 32 Bit ruby with 64 Bit ImageMagick or vice versa. Only use 32 Bit ruby with 32 Bit ImageMagick. Or use 64 Bit ruby with 64 Bit ImageMagick.

**UPDATE 2**

As @winter-young states, rmagick 2.15.4 only supports ImageMagick 6, not ImageMagick 7 (didn't test it myself)

**UPDATE 3**

As @tiefenauer points out, rmagic 2.16.0 works with ImageMagick 7.0.8. Furthermore, single quotes are needed now: `gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16'`

Comment: in my case, ld.exe failed to link a imagemagick library. I can't remember the library name. That was due to imagemagick 7 doesn't provide that library. I have to use imagemagick 6. if you use 64 bit ruby, you have to use 64 bit imagemagick. i used the 32 bit version. it failed again.

Comment: Good point, I update my answer to say don't mix 32Bit and 64Bit

Comment: Also, imagemagick 6, not 7. rmagic 2.15.4 only supports imagemagick 6.

Comment: @barlop I hadn't have the time to look into your issues, yet. But did you try Tim's answer below?

Comment: @barlop Please keep me updated. If Tim's version doesn't work, I can try my luck again

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to install rmgick since weeks. You came to my rescue. This works perfectly.

Comment: I just installed rmagick 2.16.0 on Windows together with ImageMagick 7.0.8-Q16 and it works like a charm. I had to adjust the CLI command from Raul a bit:

`gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16'`

(note the single quotes around the _--with-opt-dir_ option).

This was pointed out in the [installation instructions](https://github.com/rmagick-temp/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Windows). Looks like this version of Rmagick works with ImageMagick 7.